# Disable Home Button or system bar on tablet

Tags: android, disabled-control

I'm working on an existing Android application for medical purposes. 
The back button and home button should be disabled.

With the existing code, the back button is disabled.
For disabling the home button they used onAttachedWindow with LayoutParams TYPE KEYGUARD,
but this security hole is fixed since 4.0.

I tried a lot of similar questions, but none worked out for me.
What is the way to get this done these days?

Also, hiding the status bar on tablet (where the home & back button live) would do the trick,
so any suggestions there are equally helpful!

**Update**: also, free third party apps that do the hiding trick are okay!

Comment: You can turn your app into a launcher. If you do, all that would happen when the home button is pressed is that the user returns to your main Activity. If settings are not available through the notification shade, it would be very difficult to leave your app. But you can never prevent it entirely unless you supply both software and hardware.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a kiosk or dedicated use kinda thing, yes? You want your app to "own" the tablet and prevent other usage? I did this for an app whose sole purpose was to act as a remote control for a custom device. Basically I created two apps, a "custom launcher" app and the app that did the remote control. It's probably possible to integrate the two, but I wanted to support both dedicated and non-dedicated use. Note that I gave the launcher app a password-protected way to access settings so that I could recover the tablet at any time.

You can find a number of tutorials that will guide you through creating a custom launcher, just strip out all the stuff that makes it a generic launcher and replace it with an image button or similar that launches the actual app, or replace the launcher activity with your main app activity. Warning: I never figured out how to remove the launcher except by going into the settings.

As for hiding the system bar (notifications and status icons at the top of the screen), you'll want to use a full-screen theme like `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`.

As for hiding the home button I took this approach:

```
    View main_layout = this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
    main_layout.setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN);
```

Unfortunately the `STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN` flag is deprecated now, but I think some of the other options would have the same effect. Regardless, the best you can achieve within Android's intended use is to temporarily hide the navigation buttons (home and back). A tap on the screen will bring them back.